# showing several JS variables value in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

is it possible to get my website 2,3 js variables in an extensions i build so i will be able to see the info behind the site i build

the extension will help me develop my sites

Comment: The inspector isn't working for you? ctrl-shift-j

Comment: what do you mean? we have several people or clients that need to tell the developer several of the dynamic values in the variables and what i want is an extension that will show all of them

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  Can you please clarify what you mean by "get my website", "2,3 js variables" and "in an extensions I build"?  If English isn't your first language (and I'm guessing it isn't), maybe try to explain your situation in a paragraph or two instead of a single sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing the variables of a given website (using [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)) is possible. Just inject your own content script, and create an script tag that reads your variables. You cannot use those variables, or modify them on your extension due to some limitations of what Content script can do. You can read the following docs on [Communication with the embedding page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication).

For example the following will read a JS variable in the webpage and transfer its contents to the background page so we can let our extension deal with it. You will notice in the background page inspector, that the variable is successfully passed:

**content_script.js**

```
// JS script injection, so that we can read the JS class 'InternalJSVariable'
var postFriendMap = function() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('transfer-dom-area');
  textarea.value = JSON.stringify(InternalJSVariable);
};

// Create a dummy textarea DOM.
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.setAttribute('id', 'transfer-dom-area');
textarea.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(textarea);

// Start injecting the JS script.
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('(' + postFriendMap + ')();'));
document.body.appendChild(script);

// Inform our world that we have received the friend map data.
chrome.extension.sendRequest({internalVariable: textarea.value});

// Clean up since we no longer need this.
document.body.removeChild(textarea);
```

**background.html**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.internalVariable) {
    var internal_object = JSON.parse(request.internalVariable);
    console.log(internal_object );
  }
});
```

Comment: you probably want to add "script.async = false" or you need an onLoad callback for the injected script