# Google Chrome Extension - Script Injections

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get my Chrome Extension to inject some javascript with `content_scripts`, using this previous ***[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263671/google-chome-application-shortcut-how-to-auto-load-javascript/9310273#9310273)*** as a reference.

### manifest.json

```
"name": "My Chrome Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://pagetoinject/script/into/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"]
}]
```

### **contenscript.js:**

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
```

*( also tried* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) *method with no success. )*

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

I keep getting this javascript error. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqMk6.png).

[image]
    `GET chrome-extension://invalid/
       (anonymous function)`

Comment: Not sure what is happening, but why don't you do this instead: `"js": ["contentscript.js","script.js"]`

Comment: Because `content_scripts` are executed in an isolated environment. I need to inject the `script.js` into the DOM so I can use that file as if it was part of the public js folder. It's explained in the first section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578761/showing-several-js-variables-value-in-chrome-extensions) does what you are trying to in the content script. It might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

1. In your manifest file, `"manifest_version": 2` is specified. This automatically activates a stricter mode, in which all extension's files are not available to web pages by default.
2. Your original code would never work, because the `<script>` element is immediately removed after injection (the script file does not have a chance to load).

As a result of 1., the following error shows up in the console:

```
Failed to load resource                             chrome-extension://invalid/
```

To fix the problem, add `script.js` to the whitelist, [`"web_accessible_resources"`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) in your `manifest file`:

```
{
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://pagetoinject/script/into/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response everything worked exactly as mentioned. Also thanks for the orginal code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263671/google-chome-application-shortcut-how-to-auto-load-javascript/9310273#9310273)

Comment: but is there a way to modify a property of `window` from a script injected this way (or any other way)?

Comment: i have tried a lot but this is the only answer that works for me

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above I notice that in your `contentscript.js` you are just adding another script i.e `script.js` Why don't you directly add `script.js` through content_scripts in `manifest.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for getting this error is if the url is being blocked by CORS. Check the network request header of the page to see if it contains Content-Security-Policy:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' http://example.com; connect-src http://example.com/; script-src http://example.com/
```

You can try opening the url in a new browser tab to verify the image url is correct:

```
chrome-extension://mjcbjlencnokpknflpneebajalcnnifo/images/pattern.jpg
```

One way around this is to use an image data URI:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7
```

Answer (score 0):

Boilerplate for Chrome extension:

https://github.com/commanddotcom/boilerplate-chrome-extension-js-injection

Answer (score -4):

The problem here is that you are using `manifest_version : 2`. If you make that `manifest-version: 1` you'll not have any problems. Version 2 restricts many such features to improve security. Refer [Google Content Security Policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contentSecurityPolicy.html) for more details on the restrictions imposed in manifest version 2. I could not find your specific case mentioned in the CSP but when I changed the manifest version to 1 and executed your code it is working fine.